# How to set post thumbnail size?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to smaller my post thumbnails from 825px to something like 150x150.
I'm using the newest version of wordpress and the "sark press" theme.

So this is my code:

**sarkpress-function.php**

```
<?php
function sarkpress_render_post_thumbnail() {
if ( post_password_required() || ! has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    return;
}

if ( is_singular() ) :
?>

<div class="post-thumbnail" itemprop="thumbnail">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('square-150'); ?>
</div>

<?php else : ?>

<a class="post-thumbnail" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
<?php the_post_thumbnail('square-150'); ?>
</a>

<?php endif; ?> // End is_singular()
}?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

include_once( get_template_directory().'/inc/sarkpress-function.php');

function sarkpress_setup() {

    if ( ! isset( $GLOBALS['$content_width'] ) ) { $GLOBALS['$content_width'] = 825; }
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );    
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array( 'search-form' ) );

    register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' ); 

    add_image_size( 'square-150', 150, 150, true );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'sarkpress_setup' );
?>
```

But it doesn't work?! My thumbnails are still 825px big.

I also tried to change the 825 at the following line in the code

```
$GLOBALS['$content_width'] = 825;
```

to something smaller, but that also didn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First add the following code to your theme **functions.php**:

```
add_image_size( 'square-150', 150, 150, true )
```

In **sarkpress-function.php** file, change this line:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('square-150'); ?>
```

You would have to regenerate your images by using **Regenerate Thumbnails** plugin

Preferences:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Nope that doesn't work for me. 
I edited the above code so you can see to what I changed it to.

BTW: you missed a ';' at the end of "add image size".